# "inherit" value doesn't inherit from ":visited" parent

Tags: css, inheritance, anchor

Consider the following HTML:

```
<a href="http://google.com">foo <span class="bar">bar</span></a>
```

and CSS:

```
a {
    text-decoration:none;
    border-bottom-width: 0px;
    border-bottom-color: green;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
}

a:visited {
    color: red;
    border-bottom-color: yellow;
}

a:hover {
    color: gray;
    border-bottom-color: gray;
}

.bar {
    color: inherit;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-color: inherit;
    border-bottom-style: inherit;
}
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/exizt/5a8Pk/12/)**

---

**What I expect:**

The "bar" word should be colored red and have a yellow bottom border (since it should inherit from `a:visited`, because `http://www.google.com` is a visited link).

**What actually happens:**

The "bar" word is blue and its bottom border is green, as it is inheriting from `a`, not `a:visited`.

It does, though, inherit from `a:hover`: it and its bottom border change color to gray.

**Question: How can I make a child of `<a>` inherit values from its `:visited` state?** I will accept solutions that involve JS and jQuery. It's critical that I keep `inherit` as value of `color` and `border-bottom-color`.

**EDIT:** Apparently, this has something to do with [patching the CSS history leak](http://www.sitepoint.com/mozilla-to-tackle-browser-css-history-privacy-leak/). Still, I wonder if it's possible to acheive what I wanted.

Comment: FYI--this appears to be a Chrome only (or perhaps webkit in general, I don't have Safari to test with) bug, as my Firefox and IE10 are acting as you expect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Unfortunately, Extra Mark-up Appears to be Needed

This was tested in FF22, IE9+ (IE8 for the CSS2 version), and Chrome28.

The only way I have found (and probably the *only* way it will work at all given the security features) to get the color differentiation you desire based off *inherited* control from the `a` and `a:visited` states is by *some extra mark-up in the html*.

Specifically, all the text outside the `.bar` needs to be wrapped in its own `span` (or two `span` elements, if text also followed `.bar`), and then the `.bar` text needs a double wrapping. I assume this works because it is using the [normal default inheriting of the `color` value](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#propdef-color) for `.bar` (which [also controls the default `border-color`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#border-color-properties)), and so it allows the `:visited` text color state to pass to `.bar`.

Here's the code (I made new lines for the html display just to make the extra mark-up more visible):

**UPDATED for *unvisited* bottom border color control.**

[**See the fiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/RmS64/4/)

**HTML**

```
<a href="http://google.com">
  <span>foo </span>
  <span class="bar">
    <span>bar</span>
  </span>
</a>
```

**CSS (CSS3 version)**

```css
a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color: green; /* controls unvisited border color */
    border-bottom-width: 0px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
}

a span:not(.bar) {
    color: blue; /* sets text color of unvisited links */
}

a:visited {
    color: yellow; /*sets border color of visited links */
}

a:visited span:not(.bar) {
    color: red; /* sets text color of visited links */
}

a:hover span:nth-child(n) { 
    /* nth-child(n) selects all, but is needed to override specificity of
       :not(.bar) in the previous selector. NOTE: because all the text must be
       wrapped in a child span, there is no need to define just the a:hover
       selector without the following span, unless other links will use this
       without a .bar nesting
    */
    color: gray; /* sets text and border color when hovered */
    /* eliminated unneeded border-color property */
}

.bar {
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-style: inherit;
    /* border-color uses color property of <a> in whatever state it is in */
}
```

**CSS2 (if IE8 browser support is needed)**

You must *conditionally feed* a different set of css for the various `a` element states to IE8 (the base `a` code is the same). This cannot be combined with the above in any way, else it will mess up the working needed for Chrome.

[**See the fiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/5a8Pk/44/embedded/result/)

```css
a span {
    color: blue;
}

a:visited {
    color: yellow;
}

a:visited span {
    color: red;
}

a:visited span.bar {
    color: inherit;
}

a:hover span,
a:hover span.bar {
    color: gray;
}
```

Comment: Woah, that's great. There is a limitation, however: http://jsfiddle.net/exizt/RmS64/ -- `border-bottom-color` of an *un*visited link can't be styled then, can it?

Comment: The key in this case is to think of the `color` property of `a` as only controlling the `border-color` and explicitly overriding the text color through the `span`, so control of the *un*visited link can be explicitly achieved: http://jsfiddle.net/RmS64/2/.

Comment: @exizt: I just updated the answer to give unvisited border control.

Comment: @ScottS This is simply stunning. I can't help but wonder what your thought process was when figuring this out.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/exizt/Te63t/1/ -- I made a jsFiddle with annotated CSS and a use case (relevant to some languages' typography).

Comment: @exizt: My thought process: "is there any possible way to push pure HTML and CSS to make a seemingly impossible solution happen?" (that is my favorite part of css). The solution came by meditating further on the fact that the only thing that seemed to (without fail) _inherit_ from `:visited` was `color` and only if done by _default_. Since `border-color` derives its base color from it (which I did not realize until studying for this question), the solution had to reside in those facts. Not every property could be so controlled, but `border-color` could be because of its default specifications.

Answer (score 1):

It works fine just remove the `color: inherit;` and `border-bottom-color: inherit;`

Inherit sets it back to the original as it is part of the `<a>` so it has nothing to inherit

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Hive7/5a8Pk/3/

Comment: It's critical that I keep `inherit` as value of `color` and `border-bottom-color`. Updated the question.

Comment: inherit seems to just set it back to the original and as it is part of the `<a>` tag it is not necessary

Comment: @exizt: I agree with Oliver. The [`color` property always inherits by default](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#propdef-color). Additionally, the [`border-color` property always is set as default to the `color` property value](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#border-color-properties). So you don't need either of those declarations because your `border-color` is desired to be the same as your `color` value, which will inherit (correctly it seems) by default without declaring `inherit`.

Comment: @ScottS Ah, then, my question was confusing -- I'm sorry. I meant that `border-color` shouldn't neccessarily be equal to `color`, that's why it's inherited from `a:visited`.

Comment: Ah no it doesn't matter

Comment: @OliverCole http://jsfiddle.net/exizt/5a8Pk/11/ -- the goal is to make the bottom border's color on `bar` yellow. (without resorting to `a:visited .bar` selector)