# Is there no known way to get visited links with jQuery in modern browsers?

Tags: javascript, css

In 2010 major browser vendors patched a hole that allowed sniffing through user's history: [Mozilla to Tackle Browser CSS History Privacy Leak](http://www.sitepoint.com/mozilla-to-tackle-browser-css-history-privacy-leak/)

The proposed solution boiled down to these points:

> 1. Visited links can only be differentiated by color: foreground, background, outline, border, SVG stroke, and fill colors.
> 2. All style rules for visited and unvisited links will be resolved at the same time, and before any link styles are applied.
> 3. When JavaScript is used to query the computed style of links, only the unvisited style values will be returned.

There are some [known limitations](http://dbaron.org/mozilla/visited-privacy#limits).

The question is: **Is there no known way to select visited links via Javascript in modern browsers?**

Comment: Why do you want to defeat a security feature?

Comment: For styling purposes, actually! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17686842/inherit-value-doesnt-inherit-from-visited-parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. (If there is, it's a security bug and probably won't exist for long.)

If all you care about is styling, you should be able to achieve it through CSS, but through what is displayed on screen should be the only way to observe it being visited.

Comment: Please consider solving the linked problem, because at the moment I'm at a complete loss. Apparently, CSS inheritance is messed with by the patching of the security hole.

Comment: "it's a security bug and probably won't exist for long" -- this is a good point, though